# ошибка при поиске четных чисел в Python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь проверить являются ли числа чётными, но с определённого числа начинаются несоответствия, например
если разделить чётное число на 2 с остатком и без остатка не соблюдается равенство?

```
37889062373143906/2 == 37889062373143906//2
```

Хотя разность этих чисел равна нулю

```
37889062373143906/2 - 37889062373143906//2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обычном делении (и при вычитании) в `Python` числа всегда приводятся к типу `float` (число двойной точности). А при целочисленном — не приводятся и остаются в классе `int` (число бесконечной точности).

На платформах [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) мантисса чисел двойной точности содержит 53 бита:

```py
import sys

sys.float_info.mant_dig  # 53
```

Но Ваше число содержит 54 бита (55 после деления - 1 подразумевающийся). Таким образом, число просто не помещается в мантиссу и округляется, из-за чего Вы получаете неточный результат.

---

Проверяйте на чётность по остатку от деления на 2:

```py
num % 2 == 0
```